# How to order by in each function in jquery for dropdown html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I want to order by descending or ascending base on the id,or key.Here is how i tried,right now is giving me the actual default value, ascending base on the key.I want to descending base on the key.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="stage"]').on('change', function() {
            var stateID = $(this).val();
            if(stateID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/myform/ajax/'+stateID,
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {

                        $('select[name="status"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="status"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                        });

                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="status"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the json encode results,I changed the descending the key , but now showing by descending the key .

```html
{"7":"Send Viber Message","6":"Unpaid: Cannot Contact","5":"Paid: Cannot Contact","4":"Not Active","3":"Not interested","2":"Interested, ask for Application Date","1":"Interested, Awaiting CV"}
```

Any helps would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to use a JavaScript `Array` with `Object.keys`. First get the keys of the JSON response and sort them. Next, push them into an array. Finally, pass them to your callback function. Right now it sorts in descending order, if you want to change the order simply change the `keys.sort` function.

By the way, I changed "GET" to "POST" in my fiddle only because I had trouble getting GET to work in jsfiddle

```
function sortResults(dataObj) {
    var keys = Object.keys(dataObj);
    keys.sort(function(a, b) {
    var firstNumber = Number(a);
    var secondNumber = Number(b);
    if(firstNumber > secondNumber){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
  });

  var sortedArray = [];
  for(var i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];
    var val = dataObj[key];
    sortedArray.push({"key":key, "value":val});
  }
  return sortedArray;
}
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jchaplin2/225dvh56/1/)

Comment: Thanks bro, you saved my life.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.